# How do you call Airdrop in the web page and share the specified URL?

Tags: javascript

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

I need to click the share button when the user is browsing the page, and call Airdrop to share a specified URL instead of the page address (URL) that the user is currently browsing

Comment: By Airdrop do you mean the macOS feature? Because if so, there is no JavaScript API for that. By the way, welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to check out the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Just use it on the Safari of the iPhone phone, about this JavaScript API that is not related?